# Area inside a circle cut by two lines

Tags: geometry

How can I calculate this green area at the figure below ;the area inside a circle cut by two lines?

Where coordinates of the lines, radius of the circle is given.

[image: img]

Comment: Try using integration.

Comment: See [Circular segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment)

Comment: I'd add the area of the largest triangle in the green region to the largest segment.

Comment: Could you give us the coordinates of the two lines and the circle radius? Calculus may be the easiest way to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

In the diagram below, we require the area of $BDC$. (There should be point $E$ making $OE$ the horizontal radius.)

[image]

Area of sectors $OAB$ is $\frac{1}{2}r^2\arcsin(x/r)$. (arcsin in radians.)

Area of sector $OCE$ is $\frac{1}{2}r^2\arcsin(y/r)$.

Area of triangle $OXB$ is $\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$.

Area of triangle $OYC$ is $\frac{1}{2}y\sqrt{r^2-y^2}$.

So adding up all the areas $$BCD+OAB+OXB+OCE+OYC=\pi r^2/4+OXDY$$

Hence the answer.

$$BCD = \frac{r^2}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin\frac{x}{r}-\arcsin\frac{y}{r}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\left(x\sqrt{r^2-x^2}+y\sqrt{r^2-y^2}-2xy\right)$$

Comment: Though this is a wonderful solution, I'm not certain OP's diagram ensured the lines to be at right-angles. This may not be the general solution they were looking for.

Comment: Asker mentioned 'coordinates' of the lines; I'm assuming $x$ and $y$ given.

Comment: @Graviton : I disagree. What else could the “coordinates” of the lines mean other than their being of the form $x=a$ and $y=b$?

Comment: Very nice, +1 for you

Comment: @MPW Very true. Though perhaps unlikely, I could argue that the word choice of "coordinates" simply refers to the coordinates of intersections being known.

Comment: This is beautiful, however, how is the angle AOB, COE are arcsin x, arcsin y?

Comment: Take a horizontal line from $B$ to cut $OA$ at $F$. Then $FB=OX=x$. So angle $\sin AOB=x/r$. Thanks for spotting the error!

Answer (score 2):

### Calculus-free method using geometry:

[image]

This method involves adding the area of the triangle $ABC$ to the circular segment of the chord $AB$.

Using the formula for the area of a SSA (side-side-angle) triangle (light-green region), We find that the area of the triangle $ABC$ is

$$\frac{1}{2}(AC)(BC)\sin(\angle ACB)$$

Using the formula for the area of a circular segment (dark-green region), we find the area of the segment of the chord $AB$ is

$$\frac{1}{2}(OA)^2(\angle AOB - \sin(\angle AOB))$$

(Angles are in radians)

Therefore, the area of the whole green region is

$$\frac{1}{2}(AC)(BC)\sin(\angle ACB)+\frac{1}{2}(OA)^2(\angle AOB - \sin(\angle AOB))$$

Depending on your coordinate scheme, these values can be found by solving the equations for both red lines and the circle.

Comment: Very nice and intuitive!